# Почему Djando include не видит приложение

Tags: django, python-3.6

Начал изучать джанго, нужно было включить 1 urls файл в другой с помощью этого окда

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls"))
]
```

Включаемый файл находится в папке main(скри содержимого папок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке запустить тестировачный сервер, в консоль выводится ошибка

> yte/treningsyte/urls.py", line 21, in 
> path('', include('main.urls'))   File "/home/anton/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py",
> line 34, in include
> urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main.urls'

Почему include не видит включаемый файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш файл `urls.py` в приложении `main` находиться ещё во вложенной папке `migrations`. Перетащите `urls.py` в основной каталог `main`.